Fixing minor errors in paper after revision is submitted?
In a paper we have re-submitted after revision I found some minor errors:
For example one graph should be labeled g/ml but is labeled mg/ml accidentally. As well, in one of the raw data source tables for a graph, we forgot to paste the X values in so that column is just blank right now, but all the Y values are there.
Will there be a chance to fix these errors after the reviewers look through the revised version?

Just email the editor and let them know.

If the paper is accepted, you will have the opportunity to upload the final version for publication, incorporating these revisions. Following that, the production team will format your paper according to the journal's editorial guidelines. You will then receive the proofs of this version through the journal's online publishing system, which allows you to submit minor fixes and comments for the production team, if needed.
In summary, you will have at least two more chances to fix these minor mistakes.

May depend on field or journal: After acceptance, in all my papers the next obvious and also the last opportunity to fix such errors were the proofs. Bigger corrections then may trigger another editorial decision afaik. You could still message the journal proactively before getting the proofs, of course.

Yes, I'm only talking about minor corrections as this is what OP asked. This is likely field and journal dependent, but my experience is that even when the paper is accepted without comments from reviewers the journal asks you to confirm/upload the latest version of your manuscript, and there is room for minor corrections.

Great, thank you. Good to know there will be a chance to change these, all the other mistakes are just random tick marks got separated from their graphs in the figures or source data titles are missing a word, so was hoping there would be a chance to re-submit final versions with these things fixed if it was accepted
